# flutter [VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(203)] Error retrieving thread information: (os/kern) invalid argument

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm getting this error rarely in the app while using to run the app on IOS devices, I don't know which code should I show here because this error rarely it appears and in different screens.

Some told me that maybe it's related for using MacBook with M1 chip!

Comment: Try updating Flutter and the Xcode to the latest version to see if it resolves the issue. Try debugging the issue by looking at the stack trace or logging more information when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I use MacBook Pro with M1 chip too, and I encountered the same error.
The steps I've done to resolve this error:

```
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
```

Check if everything is ok with:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Go to /ios folder:

```
pod install
```

Run the project again.
And the error disappeared.
Hope this helps!